# PHP - How to replace code country for name?

Tags: php

I have that code:

```
<?php echo esc_html($resume->candidate_location) ?> <?php $string= esc_html($resume->candidate_country);
$search  = array("4", "248", "8", "12", "16", "20", "24", "660", "10", "28", "32", "51", "533", "36", "40", "31", "44", "48", "50", "52", "112", "56", "84", "204", "60", "64", "68", "535", "70", "72", "74", "76", "86", "96", "100", "854", "108", "116", "120", "124", "132", "136", "140", "148", "152", "156", "162", "166", "170", "174", "178", "180", "184", "188", "384", "191", "192", "531", "196", "203", "208", "262", "212", "214", "218", "818", "222", "226", "232", "233", "231", "238", "234", "242", "246", "250", "254", "258", "260", "266", "270", "268", "276", "288", "292", "300", "304", "308", "312", "316", "320", "324", "624", "328", "332", "334", "336", "340", "344", "348", "352", "356", "360", "364", "368", "372", "376", "380", "388", "392", "400", "398", "404", "296", "408", "410", "414", "417", "418", "428", "422", "426", "430", "434", "438", "440", "442", "446", "807", "450", "454", "458", "462", "466", "470", "584", "474", "478", "480", "175", "484", "583", "498", "492", "496", "499", "500", "504", "508", "104", "516", "520", "524", "528", "540", "554", "558", "562", "566", "570", "574", "580", "578", "512", "586", "585", "275", "591", "598", "600", "604", "608", "612", "616", "620", "630", "634", "638", "642", "643", "646", "654", "659", "662", "666", "670", "882", "674", "678", "682", "686", "688", "690", "694", "702", "534", "703", "705", "90", "706", "710", "239", "724", "144", "736", "740", "744", "748", "752", "756 ", "760", "158", "762", "834", "764", "626", "768", "772", "776", "780", "788", "792", "795", "796", "798", "800", "804", "784", "826", "840", "581", "858", "860", "548", "862", "704", "92", "850", "876", "732", "887", "894", "716");
$replace = array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegowina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia (Hrvatska)", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "France Metropolitan", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard and Mc Donald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao, People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Moldova, Republic of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Helena", "St. Pierre and Miquelon", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan, Province of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (British)", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe");
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $string); ?>
```

**I would like to modify this code to show:**

if $string is 4 = Afghanistan
if $string is 248 = Albania

Because now when echo is *756* then I see:
"*7Belize*", but should be: *Switzerland*

How could I fix it to show excactly country by code? I did tried find some solution, but I can't hanlde with it. Under is list of country in different format:

```
"4" => "Afghanistan"
"248" => "Åland Islands"
"8" => "Albania"
"12" => "Algeria"
"16" => "American Samoa"
"20" => "Andorra"
"24" => "Angola"
"660" => "Anguilla"
"10" => "Antarctica"
"28" => "Antigua and Barbuda"
"32" => "Argentina"
"51" => "Armenia"
"533" => "Aruba"
"36" => "Australia"
"40" => "Austria"
"31" => "Azerbaijan"
"44" => "Bahamas"
"48" => "Bahrain"
"50" => "Bangladesh"
"52" => "Barbados"
"112" => "Belarus"
"56" => "Belgium"
"84" => "Belize"
"204" => "Benin"
"60" => "Bermuda"
"64" => "Bhutan"
"68" => "Bolivia"
"535" => "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba"
"70" => "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
"72" => "Botswana"
"74" => "Bouvet Island"
"76" => "Brazil"
"86" => "British Indian Ocean Territory"
"96" => "Brunei Darussalam"
"100" => "Bulgaria"
"854" => "Burkina Faso"
"108" => "Burundi"
"116" => "Cambodia"
"120" => "Cameroon"
"124" => "Canada"
"132" => "Cape Verde"
"136" => "Cayman Islands"
"140" => "Central African Republic"
"148" => "Chad"
"152" => "Chile"
"156" => "China"
"162" => "Christmas Island"
"166" => "Cocos (Keeling) Islands"
"170" => "Colombia"
"174" => "Comoros"
"178" => "Congo"
"180" => "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the"
"184" => "Cook Islands"
"188" => "Costa Rica"
"384" => "Cote D'Ivoire"
"191" => "Croatia"
"192" => "Cuba"
"531" => "Curacao"
"196" => "Cyprus"
"203" => "Czech Republic"
"208" => "Denmark"
"262" => "Djibouti"
"212" => "Dominica"
"214" => "Dominican Republic"
"218" => "Ecuador"
"818" => "Egypt"
"222" => "El Salvador"
"226" => "Equatorial Guinea"
"232" => "Eritrea"
"233" => "Estonia"
"231" => "Ethiopia"
"238" => "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)"
"234" => "Faroe Islands"
"242" => "Fiji"
"246" => "Finland"
"250" => "France"
"254" => "French Guiana"
"258" => "French Polynesia"
"260" => "French Southern Territories"
"266" => "Gabon"
"270" => "Gambia"
"268" => "Georgia"
"276" => "Germany"
"288" => "Ghana"
"292" => "Gibraltar"
"300" => "Greece"
"304" => "Greenland"
"308" => "Grenada"
"312" => "Guadeloupe"
"316" => "Guam"
"320" => "Guatemala"
"324" => "Guinea"
"624" => "Guinea-Bissau"
"328" => "Guyana"
"332" => "Haiti"
"334" => "Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands"
"336" => "Holy See (Vatican City State)"
"340" => "Honduras"
"344" => "Hong Kong"
"348" => "Hungary"
"352" => "Iceland"
"356" => "India"
"360" => "Indonesia"
"364" => "Iran, Islamic Republic of"
"368" => "Iraq"
"372" => "Ireland"
"376" => "Israel"
"380" => "Italy"
"388" => "Jamaica"
"392" => "Japan"
"400" => "Jordan"
"398" => "Kazakhstan"
"404" => "Kenya"
"296" => "Kiribati"
"408" => "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of"
"410" => "Korea, Republic of"
"414" => "Kuwait"
"417" => "Kyrgyzstan"
"418" => "Lao People's Democratic Republic"
"428" => "Latvia"
"422" => "Lebanon"
"426" => "Lesotho"
"430" => "Liberia"
"434" => "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya"
"438" => "Liechtenstein"
"440" => "Lithuania"
"442" => "Luxembourg"
"446" => "Macao"
"807" => "Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of"
"450" => "Madagascar"
"454" => "Malawi"
"458" => "Malaysia"
"462" => "Maldives"
"466" => "Mali"
"470" => "Malta"
"584" => "Marshall Islands"
"474" => "Martinique"
"478" => "Mauritania"
"480" => "Mauritius"
"175" => "Mayotte"
"484" => "Mexico"
"583" => "Micronesia, Federated States of"
"498" => "Moldova, Republic of"
"492" => "Monaco"
"496" => "Mongolia"
"499" => "Montenegro"
"500" => "Montserrat"
"504" => "Morocco"
"508" => "Mozambique"
"104" => "Myanmar"
"516" => "Namibia"
"520" => "Nauru"
"524" => "Nepal"
"528" => "Netherlands"
"540" => "New Caledonia"
"554" => "New Zealand"
"558" => "Nicaragua"
"562" => "Niger"
"566" => "Nigeria"
"570" => "Niue"
"574" => "Norfolk Island"
"580" => "Northern Mariana Islands"
"578" => "Norway"
"512" => "Oman"
"586" => "Pakistan"
"585" => "Palau"
"275" => "Palestinian Territory, Occupied"
"591" => "Panama"
"598" => "Papua New Guinea"
"600" => "Paraguay"
"604" => "Peru"
"608" => "Philippines"
"612" => "Pitcairn"
"616" => "Poland"
"620" => "Portugal"
"630" => "Puerto Rico"
"634" => "Qatar"
"638" => "Reunion"
"642" => "Romania"
"643" => "Russian Federation"
"646" => "Rwanda"
"654" => "Saint Helena"
"659" => "Saint Kitts and Nevis"
"662" => "Saint Lucia"
"666" => "Saint Pierre and Miquelon"
"670" => "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"
"882" => "Samoa"
"674" => "San Marino"
"678" => "Sao Tome and Principe"
"682" => "Saudi Arabia"
"686" => "Senegal"
"688" => "Serbia"
"690" => "Seychelles"
"694" => "Sierra Leone"
"702" => "Singapore"
"534" => "Sint Maarten"
"703" => "Slovakia"
"705" => "Slovenia"
"90" => "Solomon Islands"
"706" => "Somalia"
"710" => "South Africa"
"239" => "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"
"724" => "Spain"
"144" => "Sri Lanka"
"736" => "Sudan"
"740" => "Suriname"
"744" => "Svalbard and Jan Mayen"
"748" => "Swaziland"
"752" => "Sweden"
"756" => "Switzerland"
"760" => "Syrian Arab Republic"
"158" => "Taiwan, Province of China"
"762" => "Tajikistan"
"834" => "Tanzania, United Republic of"
"764" => "Thailand"
"626" => "Timor-Leste"
"768" => "Togo"
"772" => "Tokelau"
"776" => "Tonga"
"780" => "Trinidad and Tobago"
"788" => "Tunisia"
"792" => "Turkey"
"795" => "Turkmenistan"
"796" => "Turks and Caicos Islands"
"798" => "Tuvalu"
"800" => "Uganda"
"804" => "Ukraine"
"784" => "United Arab Emirates"
"826" => "United Kingdom"
"840" => "United States"
"581" => "United States Minor Outlying Islands"
"858" => "Uruguay"
"860" => "Uzbekistan"
"548" => "Vanuatu"
"862" => "Venezuela"
"704" => "Viet Nam"
"92" => "Virgin Islands, British"
"850" => "Virgin Islands, U.s."
"876" => "Wallis and Futuna"
"732" => "Western Sahara"
"887" => "Yemen"
"894" => "Zambia"
"716" => "Zimbabwe"
```

Could someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Check out the `intval()` php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: You need to loop $search the array until you find your current country code.  Once you find it the loop counter should be the same for the $replace array.  So,if the first loop counter finds the code at position 'i', then $replace[i] will show the name.

Comment: Is there a reason why your search and replace arrays are of different sizes? `243` vs `239`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the array `$search` by length, and change the `$replace` accordingly. So, the number `756` will be replaced before the number `56`.

Based on you given associative array:

```
$arr  = array(
  "56" => "Belgium",
  "756" => "Switzerland",
//...
);
krsort($arr);
$str = '756' ;
$out = str_replace(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr), $str);
echo $out;
```

output:

> Switzerland

Here is a working [demo](https://3v4l.org/JNQtR).

Another example:

```
$str = '756 - 56' ;
$out = str_replace(array_keys($arr),array_values($arr),$str);
echo $out ;
```

output:

> Switzerland - Belgium